# Rails 3, changing field in model from string to datetime type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When making my model, I made row type as string (I wasn't aware of datetime at the time). Currently I have plenty of records that have that row filled. Is there a safe way to convert the model's row to datetime through a migration - besides just removing it, and then adding it back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accordingly to the documentation this is an example of migration that transforms a string in datetime. I'm not sure it will work so you may want to try it out on a dev/stage env before going to the prod env.

```
class ChangeColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :created_at, :datetime

  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :created_at, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: MySQL seems to do an internal `CONVERT(users.created_at, DATETIME)` -- I found that this worked seamlessly given that my strings in the created_at column were correctly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is `change_column`

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column